# How can I optimise in term of time this python code

Tags: python, json, time

I write this code but I find it very slow and I don't know how to really improve it in term of time. `data` is a json object with approximately 70 000 key in it. I think the slowest part is the `actors` part because i'm iterating on a list (which contain at most 3 elements).

```
genres_number = {}
actors_number = {}    
for movie in data:
    for genre in data[movie]["genres"]:
        if data[movie]["actors"] != None:
            for actor in data[movie]["actors"]:
                if actor not in actors_number.keys():
                    actors_number[actor] = 1
                else:
                    actors_number[actor] = actors_number[actor] + 1
        if genre not in genres_number.keys():
            genres_number[genre] = 1
        else:
            genres_number[genre] = genres_number[genre] + 1
res = []
res.append(genres_number)
res.append(actors_number)
return res
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea about how 'data' is structured?

Comment: Also, do not think about what is the slowest part, [measure it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_stats(data):
    genres_number = defaultdict(int)
    actors_number = defaultdict(int)

    for movie in data:

        actors = movie.get('actors')
        if actors:
            for actor in actors:
                actors_number[actor] += 1

        genres = movie.get('genres')
        for genre in genres:
            genres_number[actor] += 1

    res = []
    res.append(dict(genres_number))
    res.append(dict(actors_number))
    return res
```

Comment: In your version of the code you have a triple nested loop (for actors in genres in movies) however the way you reference the data indicates that genres and actors have no relationship to one another. So by converting it to this double nested structure you're not looping as many times.